# How to mixin a ruby module in between 2 other already included modules?

Tags: ruby, module

Suppose the following code exists:

```
module Foo
  def test(x)
    "Foo #{x}"
  end
end

module Bar
  def test(x)
    "Bar #{x} " + super
  end
end

class C
  include Foo
  include Bar
end

puts C.new.test(2)
# => "Bar 2 Foo 2"
```

I have no access to the code of class C nor modules Foo and Bar.

I'd like to include a module in between Foo and Bar, such that:

```
module Between
  def test(x)
    "Between " + super
  end
end

puts C.new.test(2)
# => "Bar 2 Between Foo 2"
```

How is this achieved?

Comment: It's going to be evil!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module Bar; include Between end
class C; include Bar end
puts C.new.test(2)
#=> Bar 2 Between Foo 2
```

Note, however, that in practice, this kind of senseless module juggling should be avoided.

Comment: Much simpler and more flexible than my answer, but I'm still trying to understand why `C.included_modules` ends up as `[Bar, Between, Foo, Kernel]` this way, and not `[Between, Bar, Foo, Kernel]` . . .

Comment: Interesting question. `C.ancestors` behaves well.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works perfectly. Interesting indeed how `C.included_modules` ends up, wouldn't have guessed that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just realize that `include` can override and does not return false (as oppose to require)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do it, provided you get a chance to run your code before processing the definition of C. Once defined, the order of re-despatch from super is fixed, so any third party library cannot over-ride it (no more than you could insert Between if their code runs first), it can only prepend to the list of included modules. Edit: Not strictly true, see  Boris Stitnicky's answer, which effectively makes use of prepending to a sub-list (and not to class C's list) to achieve the same result as below.

So you could do this:

```
module Foo; end; module Bar; end; module Between; end
class C
  # The first time a module is included it goes to front of #included_modules array
  include Foo
  include Between
  include Bar
end

require 'foobarlib' # or whatever untouchable thing defines C, Foo and Bar

# Define your Between (this bit could be anywhere before it is needed)
module Between
  def test(x)
    "Between " + super
  end
end

puts C.new.test(2)
# => "Bar 2 Between Foo 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that, because then one of the mixins wont work without the other, and then it really doesn't make sence to have it as a mixin. Just make a wrapper for the `test`-functions in `class C`.

```
module Foo
  def self.test(x)
    "Foo #{x}"
  end
end

module Bar
  def self.test(x)
    "Bar #{x}"
  end
end

class C
  def test(x)
    Bar::test(x) + " " + Foo::test(x)
  end
end

puts C.new.test(2)
# => "Bar 2 Foo 2"
```

If you however for some strange reasson *really* want this, then your code is almost correct.

```
module Foo
  def test(x)
    "Foo #{x}"
  end
end

module Bar
  def test(x)
    "Bar #{x} " + super(x) # <= you where missing the parameter here
  end
end

class C
  include Foo
  include Bar
end

puts C.new.test(2)
# => "Bar 2 Foo 2"
```